# Angular Electron & AudioWorklet.addModule() error DOMException: The user aborted a request

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, web-audio-api

When starting the app in development mode no problems, on build I get the error...

```
private record(mediaStream: MediaStream): void {
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();

    this.audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('./../../../assets/js/converter-processor.js').then(() =>  {
        // code
    }
    // code
}
```

Checked converter-processor.js for errors (none and does not use external modules).
Seems the file is not found?

Tried different solutions found on StakOverflow, no success ... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it seems such error happens when file is not present - it can't load.

This happens because by default the `Worklet.addModule()` api expects a URL of a JavaScript file with the module to add. Refer to the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule).

It does not have to be an external URL, we can simply provide a URL path to the static files in our `public folder` for example ->  `/assets/audio-level-processor.js`. If it can't find it, it will throw the error message below.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AbortError: The user aborted a request.

I used "assets" folder and it works.

```
await this.audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(
    '/assets/audio-level-processor.js'
  );
```